# Is "my heart has been slice and dice for you" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, american-english

I miss someone so much. Would it be correct to say:

> My heart has been sliced and diced for you.

Answer (score 1):

> *My heart has been sliced and diced for you*.

Correct? There's nothing wrong with it grammatically, but the expression "sliced and diced" is often used in a humorous way that mocks informercials from a couple decades ago. If you want the listener to truly feel your loneliness and longing, there are probably better expressions to use.

The tricky part with this kind of language is that it's hard to find something that is not overstated, overdone, or overused. It really depends: are you writing in confidentiality to a lover? Or just talking about how you miss family around the holidays?

You might try:

> *My heart aches for you*.

Comment: More of the history of "it slices and dices" available [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SlicesDicesAndMakesJulienneFries). And [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GniNeqSX5U), you can hear some of the original inspiration.